# Publish to Twitter from a web app to users' timeline with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter

I have a web app registered in Twitter and so have an app ID. I want to use that to publish content from the website to the users' timeline (on their behalf, their own content). I have it working on the server side but I'd like to know the way with jQuery to do it on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, use the [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method. Something like this should work:

```
$.post("/myTwitterUpdater.php", 
       { 'status': 'Hello world!' });
```

This is assuming that on the server side your script is named `myTwitterUpdater.php` and it accepts the status update in a parameter named `status`. Add your own authentication mechanisms as additional parameters or something on top of that, if you need that. The server should then use the Twitter [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) and more precisely its [POST statuses/update](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) resource to forward your status update to Twitter. (You said you got it working already, but for anyone else interested, just Google for "[twitter oauth php example](https://www.google.com/search?q=twitter%20oauth%20php%20example)", or substitute PHP with your language of choice.)

Twitter's OAuth-authentication is best left for the server to handle. It's [difficult to do with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550128/interacting-with-restful-apis-via-javascript) but [not impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221371/application-that-uses-oauth-and-javascript).

Comment: you mean there's no need to use the app id, the user's token...?

Comment: I mean an oauth signed request

Comment: Yes, you do need to use the OAuth mechanism. However, with JavaScript it's apparently difficult but not impossible. (Disclaimer: I haven't actually used the parts of the Twitter API that need authentication, only those that don't.) I've revised my answer, please read it again.

Comment: ok, the answer looks better now and convinced me not to do it actually :)